# %%view_email_url%% does not work in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, url, content-builder

`%%view_email_url%%` does not work in Content Builder - but it works in Classic.  Has anybody else run into this issue and how did they resolve?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the personalization string also works in Content Builder, however it isn't displayed in the preview, which I guess is the problem you are facing. In the preview it resolves to `javascript:void(0);`.

As soon as you send a test email (or a real send) it is transformed into the correct view as webpage url.

However, if you for any reason need to display it even in the subscriber preview, you can fetch it via AMPscript and display the AMPscript variable:

```
%%[
  SET @vawp = view_email_url
]%%
%%=v(@vawp)=%%
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that did not work.

Comment: Then I recommend raising a support case with Salesforce. I verified in three different accounts on different stacks and both the personalization string and the ampscript work in Content Builder.

Comment: I have had a saleforce helpdesk open since 12/6.  I used %%=v(@vawp)=%% within the href.  is that correct.  if you would not mind - show me an example

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue during **Preview and Test** option, then the "%%view_email_url%%" will work in Content builder ONLY if you generate the email preview with a VALID subscriber! See the difference below,

With valid subscriber selected for preview - the link works as expected.
[image]

WITHOUT selecting any VALID subscriber, the Email seems to get previewed, BUT the link will just have `javascript:void(0);` as demonstrated by @Markus in above answer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Vishal - but I am using valid subscribers.  It is the same test list i have been using.

Comment: Thanks for the update @user76957... can you post screenshot of the VAWP link.... so that anyone who had faced similar issue can identify by looking at the error!....

Comment: Vishal - You answered my question!  Mystery solved.  I did realize that I had to select a subscriber - to be allowed to have the box checked "Enable System Generated Links"!  Appreciate your  assistance.

Comment: Thank you.. Happy to assist :) ... you can accept my answer and click the tick mark.